# Invalid reference to variable PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm having trouble in getting started with PL/SQL
Here is my code:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
    v_cname customers.customer_name%type := '&customer_name';
    v_cardno customers.card_number%type := '&card_number';
    v_lastcid customers.customer_id%type;

BEGIN 
    SELECT customer_id INTO v_lastcid from customers
    where customer_id = (select max(customer_id) from customers);
    dbms_output.put_line(v_lastcid);

    INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name, card_number)
    VALUES(v_lastcid.NEXTVAL, v_cname, v_cardno);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

This returns an error:

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 20:
PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'V_LASTCID'
ORA-06550: line 12, column 20:
PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
ORA-06550: line 11, column 13:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Any help would me much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think v_lastcid is a sequence?  It is not.  A good place to start is reading the Oracle docs.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - why do you think the OP thinks `v_lastcid` is a sequence? The OP may not even know what a sequence is, or what `NEXTVAL` means. He (she?) described the issue, much better than many (most?) posters on this site. An explanation of sequences, as in one of the Answers below, makes perfect sense for this poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to say `MAX + 1` (see lines 7 and 12), i.e.

```
SQL> create table customers
  2    (customer_id   number,
  3     customer_name varchar2(20),
  4     card_number   varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      v_cname customers.customer_name%type := '&customer_name';
  3      v_cardno customers.card_number%type := '&card_number';
  4      v_lastcid customers.customer_id%type;
  5
  6  BEGIN
  7      SELECT nvl(max(customer_id), 0) INTO v_lastcid from customers
  8      where customer_id = (select max(customer_id) from customers);
  9      dbms_output.put_line(v_lastcid);
 10
 11      INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name, card_number)
 12      VALUES(v_lastcid + 1, v_cname, v_cardno);
 13      COMMIT;
 14  END;
 15  /
Enter value for customer_name: Little
Enter value for card_number: Foot
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from customers;

CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMER_NAME        CARD_NUMBER
----------- -------------------- --------------------
          1 Little               Foot

SQL>
```

Although it *works*, it is doomed to fail in a multi-user environment if two (or more) users fetch the same `MAX` value; insert would fail with a `DUP-VAL-ON-INDEX` error (if the ID is supposed to be unique).

Therefore, use a **sequence** (which is what `NEXTVAL` in your code suggests):

```
SQL> create sequence seq_cust;

Sequence created.

SQL> DECLARE
  2      v_cname customers.customer_name%type := '&customer_name';
  3      v_cardno customers.card_number%type := '&card_number';
  4      v_lastcid customers.customer_id%type;
  5  BEGIN
  6      INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name, card_number)
  7      VALUES(seq_cust.nextval, v_cname, v_cardno);
  8      COMMIT;
  9  END;
 10  /
Enter value for customer_name: Big
Enter value for card_number: Foot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 0):

nextval is used to get the next value from a sequence.  It's usually used to create a pseudo primary key.  You can think of it like a special function that can only be called on sequences.

v_lastcid is a variable that has the same type as the customer_id column in the customers table.  So if you had a table like this...

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS ( CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER );
```

...then v_lastcid is an integer;

If you're trying to make a dummy customer with the next highest number maybe you mean something like...

```
INSERT INTO customers(customer_id, customer_name, card_number)
VALUES(v_lastcid + 1, v_cname, v_cardno);
```

Hope this helps.